# Issue with aws cognito UI form fields in vue js

Tags: vue.js, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-vue

I'm using AWS cognito and amplify in my vue js application. Everything is working fine with pre-defined fields.

I've added the custom fields in AWS user pool attributes section. Those newly added fields are not reflecting in UI.

Here is my code for amplify config and custom fields.

HTML Code:

```
<amplify-authenticator>
     <amplify-sign-up
       slot="sign-up"
       header-text="My Project Sign-Up"
       submit-button-text="Register"
       :formFields="formFields"
     ></amplify-sign-up>
</amplify-authenticator>
```

Custom Fields JSON

```
formFields: [
        { type: 'username' },
        { type: 'password' },
        { type: 'email', inputProps: { required: true, autocomplete: 'username' } },
        { type: 'phone_number' },
        { type: 'custom:name' },
      ]
```

Result form

[image]

Custom fields are not coming in the form. Can some one please help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to be related to Stencil. See [this discussion](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/5363#issuecomment-618627713).

The solution suggested is to change `formFields` to `formFields.prop`.

E.g.

```
<amplify-authenticator>
     <amplify-sign-up
       slot="sign-up"
       header-text="My Project Sign-Up"
       submit-button-text="Register"
       :formFields.prop="formFields"
     ></amplify-sign-up>
</amplify-authenticator>
```

This worked for me using Vue 2.